# Can I disable "Unable to read dynamic function table entry at" in WinDbg Preview?

Tags: windbg

For reasons I don't know, the application I develop triggers a continuous warning when I use WinDbg Preview. It makes debugging impossible.

The only [answered question I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255930/can-i-disable-the-unable-to-read-dynamic-function-table-entry-message-in-windb) on this topic is from 2016 not valid anymore with WinDbg Preview. I tried both solutions but the messages keep coming.

Moreover the answers over there doesn't seem to explain why it happens and I really would like to know why.

FYI: I have emailed the support so it may happen that I will answer my own question to keep you updated.

Comment: For the why part: possibly buffer overflow or underrun that overwrote parts of the virtual method table.

Comment: thanks for the edit @ThomasWeller, very appreciated.